# How to add Realm name in custom email template Subject

Tags: keycloak

I have created a custom Theme for Keycloak email.

I know how to add the realm name in email body, but I didn't find how to add the realm name in the subject.

Is there any possibility to add this without the need of a custom Provider ?

Thank's !

Comment: did you find a solution to above?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same question.

So did some research(went through code), and find out that as of writing this answer, the default Freemarker-based Email Implementation doesn't even supply the subject attributes(call them variables or arguments), and the final subject string formatting is done based on an empty list of attributes.
https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/bfce612641a70e106b20b136431f0e4046b5c37f/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/email/freemarker/FreeMarkerEmailTemplateProvider.java#L162

```
 @Override
    public void sendExecuteActions(String link, long expirationInMinutes) throws EmailException {
        Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>(this.attributes);
        attributes.put("user", new ProfileBean(user));
        addLinkInfoIntoAttributes(link, expirationInMinutes, attributes);

        attributes.put("realmName", getRealmName());

        send("executeActionsSubject", "executeActions.ftl", attributes);
    }
```

Which in return calls

```
    @Override
    public void send(String subjectFormatKey, String bodyTemplate, Map<String, Object> bodyAttributes) throws EmailException {
        send(subjectFormatKey, Collections.emptyList(), bodyTemplate, bodyAttributes);
    }
```

Finally, this function gets executed

```
 protected EmailTemplate processTemplate(String subjectKey, List<Object> subjectAttributes, String template, Map<String, Object> attributes) throws EmailException {
        try {
........
            String subject = new MessageFormat(rb.getProperty(subjectKey, subjectKey), locale).format(subjectAttributes.toArray());
........
```

Throughout the code trail for `executeAction` I nowhere found any logic which allows adding dynamic-values/variables in the subject line.

To solve this I am raising an issue. I will link it once done.

## Update 1

Issue opened: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/11883

## Update 2

PR raised: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/11885

Comment: Is this an answer that solves the problem?

Comment: An answer need not directly solve the problem; the target location where code needs to be modified is added. After raising the issue, one would be able to raise a PR, and then it will depend on when it will be merged by the project admin(s). Meanwhile, someone who needs it urgently can fork and modify it as needed.

Meanwhile, the above answer will help people not waste their time searching through the internet in the hope of solution wherein actuality there exists no official explanation/solution.

Comment: Has there been any update on this topic?